# Unable to lazy load images in a jQuery Mobile application (currently using LazyLoadXT)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, lazy-loading

I am having difficulty implementing a lazy loading feature in my jQM application using [Lazy Load XT v1.0.6](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt/).

I am finding that when I scroll down the image isn't being shown, however when I switch to a different tab in my browser and then switch back the images are there. I thought this may be a strange quirk of Firefox, however this happens on both the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome.

```
<img src="/img/default-img.jpg" data-src="/img/product/1872.jpg" class="product_image" width="200" height="300">
```

What is happening here? Is pageinit the correct event for this code?

I am using jQuery Mobile v1.3.1.

This is the code I am using to attempt to lazy load my images when the user scrolls down.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function (event, ui) {
    var page = $(event.target);
    page.find(".container .product_image").lazyLoadXT();
});
```

I have tried a few plugins, with little success so if there is another approach to this then please shout.

Comment: Seems to work without initializing lazyload: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/o24a4vzg/, Can you make the fiddle reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes). The script detects new elements and visibility changes to those automatically. So you don't need to write any JS code. You only need to add the script and add a `data-src` attribute as also the class `lazyload` to your images.